# Java Microsoft Excel API

Tags: java, excel

Does anyone know if there is an API for java by Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Did you try typing "java excel api" in the search box in the upper right corner?

Answer (score 9):

You have [`APache POI`](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) and [`JExcelApi`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to mention two open source variants. The former supports up to version 2008 and the latter up to version 2003. Personally I prefer the  syntax of the former.

Comment: Vote for POI - it most efficient and flexible. And supports UTF-8!

Comment: @ninja: on the contrary, JXcel is orders of magnitude more efficient than POI in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

Extensive List of Products currently available:

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

[OpenXls](http://www.extentech.com/estore/product_detail.jsp?product_group_id=228)

[JEXCEL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

[JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/)

[xlSQL](http://xlsql.sourceforge.net/)

[JCOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcom)

Personally, `POI` will be the best option, but it involves a lot of coding effort compared to JXLS, which is a wrapper over POI. In `JXLS` all you need to do is to create XLS template file with all required formatting, formulas etc using specific notation to indicate placement of data and then write a couple lines of code to invoke jXLS engine passing XLS template and the exported data as parameters. Catch in Jxls is the data in every cell must be a `JavaBean`.

Comment: If the library you're recommending can do something cool in a few lines of code, then providing said lines of code bumps your answer up a notch.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to write to / read from Microsoft Formats (including Excel) you are looking for [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[Apache POI-HSSF and POI-XSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

- every elaborate API
- works with xlsx files

[JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

- lightweight API, easier to learn
- MUCH faster on big spreadsheets (10000's of lines)
- no support (yet?) for Excel 2007+ xlsx files

Have a look at [jXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) as well, it's a library on top of POI that allows you to use Excel files as templates.

Comment: FWIW, JExcelAPI is never going to support xlsx/xlsm files. To my disappointment, we're having to move on. So far the other two libraries we've tried, POI and Aspose.Cells, are both *much* worse on resources. (We haven't yet tried the POI Event API as that's a very big change from our current reusable code.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few, but [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is a popular and free one.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend checking out JODConverter.